Discriminant formula - do the coefficients include their signs?
Beginner here. Can I ask someone to explain to me the following?
Given the following general form of quadratic equation:
$$
ax^2+bx+c=0
$$
and the following formula for discriminant:
$$
D=b^2−4ac,
$$
what is the $b$ coefficient in the following equation?
$$
2x^2 - 2x = 0
$$
Is it $-2$ or $2$?
Does the coefficient count with the positive/negative sign?
I am confused because for example $-2^2= -4$, and so here the sign is not taken into consideration, unless it's $(-2)^2$.

In that equation the coefficient of $x$ is $b = -2$.

$bx = -2x \implies b = -2$

@DevelBase2    $(-2)^2≠(-4)$

Yes, pay attention to the sign.
The quadratic formula gives you an explicit expression for the solutions to the quadratic polynomial equation
$$
ax^2 + bx + c = 0,
\tag{1}
$$
where $a$, $b$, and $c$ can be any real numbers with the caveat that $a \neq 0$ (otherwise, it wouldn't be quadratic).
These coefficients can be negative numbers and you plug them in just the same. The discriminant is $D = b^2 - 4ac$, and if $D > 0$, we get two distinct solutions to the equation (1)
$$
x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{D}}{2a}.
$$
In your example equation $2x^2 - 2x = 0$, we have
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
a &= 2 \\
b &= -2 \\
c &= 0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
So, $D = (-2)^2 - 4(2)(0) = 4$, and the solutions are
$$
x = \frac{-(-2) \pm \sqrt{4}}{2(2)} 
= \frac{2 \pm 2}{4}
\quad\implies\quad
x = 1 \;\text{or}\; x = 0.
$$
In this case, where the constant term vanishes, it's easier to solve the equation by factoring:
\begin{align}
2(x^2 - x) &= 0 \\
2x(x - 1) &= 0 \\
x(x - 1) &= 0, 
\end{align}
from which we again conclude that either $x = 0$ or $x - 1 = 0$, i.e., $x = 1$.

General
If, the general form is
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$
Then, for any value of $b$, the coefficient of the equation must be with the sign.
Specific Answer
The values of the coefficients are :
$a=+2$, $b=-2$

It is $-2$ .

Does the coefficient count with the positive/negative sign?

Yes the coefficient count with the sign.
In your case the discriminant would be:
$D = (-2)^2 -4(2)(0)$
$D = 4 - 0$
$D = 4$
Further, whenever you are given a general form with a $+$ sign you would eventually conside the value to be negative if in the expression, the sign is $-$.
OR
If the sign is $-$ in the general form and in expressin it is also negative then you wouldn't count the negative sign.
For example (also for sake of convenience), if the general form had been: $ax^2 -bx + c$ then you would not consider the sign and $b = 2$.

Just rewrite everything in general form
$$
ax^2+bx+c=0
$$
You can use round brackets if helpful
$$(a)x^2+(b)x+(c)=0$$
Eg1
$$
2x^2 - 2x = 0
$$
Rewrite
$$0 = 2x^2 - 2x$$
$$= (2)x^2 - 2x$$
$$= (2)x^2 + -2x$$
$$= (2)x^2 + (-2)x$$
$$= (2)x^2 + (-2)x + 0$$
$$= (2)x^2 + (-2)x + (0)$$
Then you 'match coefficients' to see that
$$A=2, B=-2, C=0$$
Eg2
$$
-7 -5x^2 +4x = 0
$$
Rewrite
$$0 = -7 -5x^2 +4x$$
$$ = +(-7) + (-5)x^2 + (4)x$$
$$ = (-5)x^2 + (4)x +(-7)$$
Again, 'match coefficients' to see that
$$A=-5, B=4, C=-7$$

You just gave me an "aha" moment. This has been a thing I've not understood since high school and I've never found the courage to ask. Thank you sir!

@DevelBase2 i'm not surprised you're responding this way. I made this answer precisely because I didn't see other answers that have the concept of 'matching coefficients', which comes up in 'partial fraction decomposition'.  also, i edited post for the 2nd example
